# Implementing the slowly-changing background color in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, ionic2, css-animations

I've been trying to implement, in Ionic + Angular 2, a simple app that, through the whole app, the background color can slowly change, cycling between different colors.

I've had mild success with CSS keyframe animations:

```
animation: colorChange
@keyframes colorChange {
  0%   { background-color: #001514 ; }
  25%   { background-color: #a3320b ; }
  50%   { background-color: #6b0504 ; }
  75%   { background-color: #bad431 ; }
}
```

But my problem is, when a different form is pushed onto the NavCtrl, the background color on that form is, of course, back to the starting color.

I was thinking that maybe there would be a way of changing this programmatically in Angular.

Is there perhaps a way to set a sass variable at runtime through Angular?

Maybe my CSS can determine color as a value of time, this may give a similar (spectacular) effect.

Any ideas would be appreciated.